# Include several files in a theme

Tags: wordpress

I want my theme to include files such as:
about.php, contact.php, blabla.php etc.

And I want those pages to be editible through the wordpress admin interface, how should I proceed to do this?(I want the pages to exist as soon as my theme is selected, so to say I want a already predefined number of pages that is customizable).

I mean there is no problem just making links to these pages and make them use the wordpress header and footer but how can I make the content of them editible like a 'page' in the wordpress adminpanel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user Custom page template for more information regarding custom page template .. http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Yeah this is kind of what I was looking for.  Just a follow up question. If i want to seperate the wp_nav_menu to two menus. One with all sites that are of template type a,b or c and one that is of templates types d,e,f. How do I do that?

Comment: Found the answer here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/secondary-wp_nav_menu-repeating-first Thank you.